# Test retest reliability for a test taken multiple times

Tags: repeated-measures, reliability

In our study, we would like to assess the reliability of a test measuring pitch discrimination thresholds. For this, we let participants take an adaptive threshold test (staircase procedure). We repeat this test twice in the same session, so we have three blocks overall. Is there a way to measure the overall test retest reliability, i.e. how reliable the test is over the three blocks?

I appreciate any help!